# i recieve mail from same mail domain which is host mail in django

Tags: python, django, email, authentication, gmail

here is settings.py of my app

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'hk7206210@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class contactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required= True,max_length = 100,help_text = '100 
    character Max.')
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    comment = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import contactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
# Create your views here.
def contact(request):
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
    subject = 'Message from Matrimonial.com'
    message = '%s %s' %(comment,name)
    emailFrom = form.cleaned_data['email']
    emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
    send_mail(subject, message,emailFrom,emailTo)
context = locals()
template = 'contact.html'
return render(request,template,context)
```

Problem is sender and reciever is from same email address from hk7206210@gmail.com and to is also hk7206210@gmail.com i search alot but can't find the solution,help me out from this bug #

Answer (score 0):

**1) Why is sender = 'hk7206210@gmail.com'**
Your `settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` is your email account, any emails will come out of this address so your sender is 'hk7206210@gmail.com'

**2) Why is receiver = 'hk7206210@gmail.com'**
Because you wrote `emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]`

What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to send an email to what the user input in the form, it should be the opposite:

```
emailFrom = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
emailTo = [form.cleaned_data['email']]
```

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to say,your answer confuse me,please improve my code if something is wrong and clerify what needs to be what

Comment: No,I want user to send me email to my host email hk7206210@gmail.com,not me send email to user,hope you understand your code just do the opposite of it

Comment: okay tell me one thing ,does django support receiving email,I saw documentation on how to send email through django but their is nothing on how to recieve email in django.

Comment: Receiving email in django? Django is not email client.

Comment: Are you trying to do something below? 
1. You are adding  xyz@somedomain.com in your Django settings file. 
2. Then any user who sends email to xyz@somedomain.com in your Django Application.

If this is the case - where you want to read/how will you read. 

All this does not make sense!

Comment: okay sopan ,you are right but I want to recieve email from user to my email xyz@domain.com so is there any way i can do it in django,my above code make no sense my code sent email to user using my host email.